# url_launche behaves differently in local vs firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, url-launcher

I have created a simple Flutter Web App and deployed in to Firebase hosting.

I use url_launcher: ^6.0.17
I created a list of links that can be clicked to open in a new window:

```
dynamic _launchURL() async {
  final parsedUrl = Uri(
    path: url,
    scheme: 'https',
  );
  if (await canLaunchUrl(parsedUrl)) {
    await launchUrl(
      parsedUrl,
      // mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
      webOnlyWindowName: "_blank",
    );
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
    //  TODO: open window to copy url
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine in test chrome/edge but also in emulator and my phone plugged to pc (when debugging from AndroidStudio)

When I deployed to Firebase hosting it behaves in a different way - it appends url I am providing after last slash of my mian page and thus it fails.

e.g.
when I am on https://.web.app
and click a link I see in browser that it attempts to open
https://***my app name***.app/ ***target link*** in a new browser tab

As I am new to firebase I am not even sure how to troubleshoot it - e.g. get app logs etc.

Any help will be appreciated

I tried:
googling + stack overflow + playing with url_launcher params + tested on multiple browsers

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the problem was linked to url_launcher extension. I ended using deprecated API methodes - e.g. 'launch' instead of 'launchUrl' and it worked

Comment: Can you tell which version you are using. I am using 6.1.7 and the deprecated method of `launch` still not opening links